# Which Animals Have Only One Kosher Sign?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals, non-kosher-species, parashat-shemini

[Vayikra 11:4-7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm) mentions four animals that either chew their cud or have split hooves, but do not posses both kosher signs and are therefore not kosher.  At the present time, is this a complete list or only partial?  If it is only partial, where can I find a complete list?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45395/759

Comment: Can you clarify what animals are on that list? Are alpacas or babirusas on it?

Comment: For a start, you can read this - http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2011/03/camel-hare-and-hyrax.html - and related entries.