Is Capybara meat kosher?
According to Wikipedia the Capybara ...

They also regurgitate food to masticate again, similar to cud-chewing
by cattle

which would lead you to think that they conform to the Torah laws of only eating that which cheweth the cud (Like cows do), but they are rodents, I am unsure how that features into kosher certification.
source

They would need to also have split hooves. Otherwise they're no different than the camel, hare and rabbit (or hyrax), all of which are specified in the Torah as not kosher because they chew the cud but don't have split hooves.

I first read this as Chupacabra... lol

I see they have  The feet of capybaras are partially webbed and have four digits on the forefeet and three on the hind, and all have strong claws.

Doesn't give us the reasoning, but it's a no: https://outorah.org/p/5970/

R' Slifkin wrote about capybaras https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52645/759

Incidentally, their smoky flavor is especially good in soups and stews

The Da'at Zekenim, based on Vayikra 11:27, writes (on that verse) that although there are many animals who have split feet, nevertheless if they don't have hooves, they are impure.

My disappointment is immeasurable and my day is ruined.
